# Re-sending documents when signer declines

Tags: docusignapi, envelope

Is it possible to re-send the envelope when signer has declined to sign it?

In my current application, need to include option to re-send the envelope based on the recipient/signer status. Also, in my case, there is a single recipient/signer in each envelope.

I am using RESTFul APIs. Functionality is working fine in case recipients having statuses - sent, delivered, autoresponded.

But when I try to re-send the envelope when recipient declined to sign it, I am getting this error: ENVELOPE_INVALID_STATUS: Invalid envelope status. Envelope status is not one of: Created, Sent, Delivered, Correct.

API used - /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients - PUT

Request JSON

```
{
 "signers": [
     {
        "email": "'.$email_rec['email_id'].'",
        "name": "'.$email_rec['name'].'",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "roleName": "Employee"
      }
    ]
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot re-send an envelope once it has reached a terminal state: completed, declined, voided (either explicitly by sender or envelope expired).

In this case, you may want to consider cloning the declined envelope and start the transaction over from the top of the workflow. If signer attachments were added to the declined envelope they will also exist in the clone, which may lead you to instead start from scratch/clean slate.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In case, any requirement is there to send envelope which is declined, I can look into the concept of cloning the envelope.

Comment: @luis-scott we can clone envelope from ui but is there any api endpoint to clone envelope? I didn't find any in api documentation